# Why did trying to access a single dimensional array of objects as double array change the underlying object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

```
const arr = new Array(1); 
arr[0] = {x: "first", y: "second"}
arr[0][5] = "third"
console.log(arr)
// Result: [{5: "third", x: "first", y: "second"}]
```

Why did it add 5: "third" in the beginning like that? How does JS handle this under the hood?

Comment: `arr[0]` refers to an object in memory, which is also present in the array. `arr[0][5] = "third"` mutates that object.

Comment: You've added the key-value pair `5: "third"` to the object referenced by `arr[0]`... if that doesn't answer your question, can you elaborate what specifically you're confused about?

Comment: And what were you expecting to happen if not to produce that result?

Comment: Honestly I was expecting an error. I though that array(2) would initialize a 2d array but of-course it didn't. The code above summarizes what I couldn't reason about which was why [5] = "third" became part of the object instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `arr[0]` is your object `{x: "first", y: "second"}`.

So, when you do `arr[0][5] = "third"`, you are saying to assign the value `"third"` to the `5` property of that same object.  So, then when you examine `arr`, you see your original object you put there with the `5` property added to it.

You could also do it this way (in case this helps you understand it better):

```js
const arr = new Array(1); 
let z = {x: "first", y: "second"};
arr[0] = z;          // assign z object into our array
z[5] = "third";      // add "5" property to the z object
console.log(arr);    // now look at the z object in our array
```

In both my code example and your code example, you assign a pointer to your object to `arr[0]`.  Then, in your example, you get that pointer again and assign it a new value with

```
arr[0][5] = "third";
```

Or, in my example, I retain a pointer to that same object and assign it a new property that way.  Both point to the same object.

And, using this syntax:

```
arr[0][5] = "third";
```

says to get the value of `arr[0]` and then assign the `5` property of that a value of `"third"`.  Keep in mind that indexing with `[5]` works for either array entries or for property values.  **If the object you are using the index assignment on is not an array (which is the case here), then Javascript tries to make a string out of the index value and assigns a property to the underlying object with that property name.**

> Why did trying to access a single dimensional array of objects as double array change the underlying object.  Why did it add 5: "third" in the beginning like that? How does JS handle this under the hood?

Because the `[5]` is not only array indexing, it's also property access.  If the underlying object you are indexing on is an array, then that gets the 6th element of the array.  If the underlying object you are indexing on is not an array (just a plain object), then that accesses the "5" property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

It works through property accessors

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Basically as you know arrays are accessed through indexes inside square brackets. In this case object properties are accessed and created through a similar thought process

Here is a summary from resource provided

> One can think of an object as an associative array (a.k.a. map, dictionary, hash, lookup table). The keys in this array are the names of the object's properties.